# If-Statement Help in PHP

Tags: php, image, if-statement, directory

So for some reason this just doesn't make sense to me.

**What Im trying to do is display 1 of 2 things:**

1. If the filesize of just 1 image in the folder is too big, display the error message I have  above.
2. If all of the filesizes are ok, display a bit of HTML code

Also, is my threshold correct if I want the limit to be 5MB?

```
<?php
$threshold = 5368709120;
$path = 'dir/'.$username;
foreach (glob($path."/{*.gif,*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.png}",GLOB_BRACE|GLOB_NOSORT) as $filename)  
{
    $size = filesize($filename);
    if ($size > $threshold) {
        exit('One or more of your photos are larger than 5MB. Resize your photos and try again.');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What doesn't make sense? Doesn't it work like you want?

Comment: No, I dont know how to write the IF Statement. If I tack on the HTML code to the bottom, it displays no matter if the filesize of all images is OK or too big. I only want the HTML code to appear if all of the filesize is OK.

Comment: you can use `5 * pow(10,6)` to get SI 5mb, or use `5 * pow(2,20)` for the old school way

Comment: I think you want `5242880` aS your threshold. (5 * 1024 * 1024)

Comment: 5MB would be 5242880 bytes.  Your number is 5GB.

Comment: is your `glob()` definitely giving back the correct list of files?

Comment: 5 megabytes is 5242880 bytes. Your if is never true...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your file limit is actually 5 gigabytes:

```
5 -> bytes = 5
5 * 1024 -> kilobytes = 5,120
5 * 1024 * 1024 -> megabytes = 5,242,880
5 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 -> gigabytes => 5,368,709,120
```

For user friendliness, you should tell the user WHICH file is too large, as well as check ALL the files before exiting. Let's say the user didn't know there was a 5 meg limit, and uploaded 50 files. 49 are too large. You're just telling the user there's a problem, not what caused the problem. Now they have to re-upload a file, then do it again. now there's 48 files too big, and around they go.

Something like this would be more appropriate

```
$limit = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5 meg
$errors = array();

foreach (glob($path."/{*.gif,*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.png}",GLOB_BRACE|GLOB_NOSORT) as $filename)  
   if (filesize($filename) > $limit) {
      $errors[] = $filename
   }
}

if (count($errors) > 0) {
   echo "The following files are too large: <ul>";
   echo implode("</li><li>", $errors);
   echo "</ul>";
} else {
   echo "Everything A-OK!";
}
```

Comment: `echo "The following files are too large: <ul><li>";
 echo implode("</li><li>", $errors);
 echo "</li></ul>";`

Comment: Thank you so much! The one '{' and two '}' before/after   $errors[] = $filename caused an error but I got it fixed. You rock!

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following so that the intention of the code was always clear:

```
$threshold = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5MB
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Your problem is that you are not calling `filesize()` on the full path of the file, just on the file name. This means that if the files resides outside the current working directory - as it looks like it does - it won't work.</strike> Apparently this is untrue with `glob()`.

Regarding `is my threshold correct if I want the limit to be 5MB`, the simple way to make sure it is correct is the calculate it instead of hard-coding it:

```
$threshold = 1024 * 1024 * 5;
```

As it is, you were looking for files over 5 GB.

Comment: glob's return values include the path, actually. Had to check it myself, but it does...

Comment: @MarcB Oh... right. I always, without fail, use `opendir()` (force of habit) but I assumed `glob()` would do basically the same thing. Duly noted.

Comment: Marc B is correct. (I also checked.) If you were using `readdir()` you only get the filename.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$threshold = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5MB
$path = 'dir/'.$username;
foreach (glob($path."/{*.gif,*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.png}",GLOB_BRACE|GLOB_NOSORT) as $filename)  
{
    $size = filesize($filename);
    if ($size > $threshold) {
        exit('One or more of your photos are larger than 5MB. Resize your photos and try      
again.');
    }
}
?>
//display html code here
```

Just add the html code anywhere after the foreach loop, since it has already passed the if 
    //$size>$threshold check(and has gone through all the images in the for loop

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, although your threshold is not. `5368709120` is 5 [GiB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GiB), you want `5000000`.

<sup>[`mega`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mega-) is just another word for million.</sup>

Comment: Huh? [Giga means billion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giga-). Obviously, 5368709120 is not 5 billion.